# Python or R -- create a SQL join using a dataframe

Tags: python, r, pandas, oracle, join

I am trying to find a way, either in R or Python, to use a dataframe as a table in an Oracle SQL statement.
It is impractical, for my objective, to:

1. Create a string out of a column and use that as a criteria (more than a 1k, which is the limit)
2. Create a new table in the database and use that (don't have access)
3. Download the entire contents of the table and merge in pandas (millions of records in the database and would bog down the db and my system)

I have found packages that will allow you to "register" a dataframe and have it act as a "table/view" to allow queries against it, but it will not allow them to be used in a query with a different connection string.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Either to allow two different connections in the same SQL statement (to Oracle and a package like DuckDB) to permit an inner join or direct link to the dataframe and allow that to be used as a table in a join?

SAS does this so effortlessly and I don't want to go back to SAS because the other functionality is not as good as Python / R, but this is a dealbreaker if I can't do database extractions.

Comment: Of your "cannot do" options, I agree: #1 is prone to many problems and #3 is the brute-force method that shouldn't be done. *However*, #2 is the best thing (imho) to do, period: insert the local frame with the multiple rows of values you need to filter based on, then select from it joining in the other table(s) you need.

Comment: Short of iterating over each row of your local frame (perhaps inefficient?), I believe your three constraints have left you with an empty domain of potential solutions.

Comment: You have a choice of writing the table to Oracle SQL and doing the join there, or reading the table from oracle and doing the join using R or Pandas. I don't see any option that doesn't involve one of those two.

Comment: [Oracle R Enterprise](https://developer.oracle.com/databases/combining-r-with-sql-for-data-analysis.html) may have some facilities but I don't have it to try it.  The obvious way to proceed is to use `dbWriteTable` in R to write the data frame to Oracle assuming  that the table on the Oracle side is much larger than the one on the R side.

Comment: From your formulation I'm not sure what you try to achieve, but possible the solution is to install your own database (check Oracle XE) - this will give you the missing **access**.

Comment: What is the 1K limit you mention? Is that some type of limit on the length of the SQL statement you are submitting to the remote database?

Comment: Tom: it's the limit to the number of items in a list that can be used in a SQL query.  If you concat too many items together from a table of results that you want to limit the secondary query to, it will fail if it goes over 1,000.  I work with lists that are routinely 20k on a where statement criteria passed from another query.

Comment: If you are just talking about number of values for IN operator just restructure your query to use multiple IN operators.  `where (x in (a,b,c)) or (x in (x,y,z))`  No idea what the performance would be but it should let you avoid some arbitrary limit on number values used with IN operator.

Comment: Tom: I'm not willing to do that.  I'd have to make 21 IN operators.  The feeder query will always have a different number of input criteria.  Today, the number was 20,453.  It grows at approx 1k a month.  The main query runs off of 50M records, so I'm not downloading those tables every run for sure.  The main thing is that this has to be repeatable without reprogramming.  Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately, it's just not practical.  :(

Comment: Maybe explore binding the data (from the dataframe) in Python as a PL/SQL 'index of' table into an anonymous PL/SQL block and then using PL/SQL capabilities like the TABLE () operator?  Check with the PL/SQL experts.

Comment: I have the same problem (2. - I can't send R nibble in an (temporary) oracle database table as a read only user). So I split my df into chunks lower than 999 rows and map the query within a function along chunks... Not ideal, longer and not accurate but it works. Will try Tom suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here -- after much research.
In short, this cannot be done.  A series of criteria, outside of a list or concat, you cannot create a dataframe in python or R and pass it through a query into a SQL Server or Oracle database.  It's unfortunate, but if you don't have permissions to write to temporary tables in the Oracle database, you're out of options.